# What's the word in English for something that increases/decreases?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expression-choice

I'm a game programmer and currently working on a generic system that works for most type of games. I have a generic piece of code, that I use on anything that could increase/decrease called `EffectCauser` - It has a bunch of parameters for it to work:

1. The target component (health, mana, speed, stamina, etc)
2. The effect methodology (`OneHit`, `Overtime`, `Permanent`, etc)
3. The effect type (`Positive`/`Negative`)
4. The effect amount.

First let me explain how this works in a couple of simple examples so that you understand better:

Let's say I wanted to create a first aid kit. I create an `EffectCauser` which will cause its effect on the `Health` component of the target object, I specify the methodology of the effect of type `OneHit` and the type of the effect to be `Positive` and an amount I choose, lets say 100 for a full heal.

Another example, if I wanted to create a Mana spell that decreases mana overtime:
I would create an effect causer that targets the `Mana` component of a target, select a methodology of `Overtime` (temporarily in other words) (filling the appropriate time values), an effect type of `Negative` this time, and an amount, like 50. (Imagine a spell in an RPG game where an enemy cast it at you, so you get -50 mana over a 10 sec time period)

And so on and so forth. I could do this for a `Speed` component, `Agility`, `Stamina`, etc.

The main thing for this to work is that all these things (Health, Mana, Speed, Stamina, etc) have to implement a common interface. I'm not being able to find the name of that interface.

One common thing between all these things, is that they increase and decrease. I thought of `IChangable` but that's very generic, maybe `IIncreasableDecreasable` but that's very long, and screaming "there's a better word than me"

Note that the convention of naming interfaces, is "IXXXable" (IMovable, ICombinable, ITransformable, etc)

So, what can I use here? what is the word that satisfies my needs?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**
To make it easy, it need not be an interface. I could create an abstract class. Interfaces define behavior, while a class is for something that exists. I just have to change my way of thinking.

Ex: an abstract `Character`, with `Player` and `Enemy` as children. `Player` and `Enemy` *are a* `Character`. (`Character` is an abstract term for `Enemy` and `Player`)

So... what *are* `Health`, `Mana`, `Speed`, etc? For one thing, they're `Components` but what else? (I can't use `Component` here due to ambiguity as well). What about `PlayerAttribute`? well, for one thing I can attach `Health` to an enemy, not just the player. So... `CharacterAttribute` is good? nop, still ambiguous. (Attribute means a total separate thing in .NET)... I'm out of words :(

If you ever played an RPG game, what would a common name be to all your player stuff? (health, mana, agility, stamina, speed, dexterity, etc)

Comment: 'Effecter' might be a better choice than 'EffectCauser', too - they mean the same thing. Then you can have the corresponding 'Effectee', for the thing that receives the effect.

Comment: changeable seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few ideas: IVariable (don't think it will suit your needs here due to "variable" ambiguity), IAdjustable, IModifiable, IMutable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right, I can't use IVariable. But all the words you suggested, are still all too general (for example, when somebody reads that X is "Adjustable" or "Modifiable", he can't really tell that X is something that has a value, which he could increase/decrease (perform adding/subtraction operations on)). Could there be something else in common, between those components that I could use instead of increasing/decreasing? (i.e. the Health, Mana, etc)

Comment: How about iGauge

Comment: Hm, if I see that a numeric value is changeable, modifiable etc., I assume that this value can be subject to a change. It can be subtraction, addition, division, multiplication... Unless you want to underline that only subtraction and addition are only possible here, then it is quite hard to come up with such word. I'll think about it more :)

Comment: @mplungjan Doesn't fit the convention "IXXXable", sadly

Comment: @Vilmar I made an edit, check it out! Might make the guessing easier. It need not necessarily be an interface, I could change my way of thinking, and use an abstract class.

Comment: IFluctuatable sounds ghastly, but does appear to describe what you want, I think.

Comment: @vexe, as for your edit: in the RPGs I played these are mostly referred to as _"attributes"_, which you said you cannot use. Sometimes they are called _"abilities"_, _"characteristics"_ or _"statistics"_. How about `CharacterStats`?

Comment: Maybe I'll reconsider 'CharacterAttribute'. In the meantime, 'CharacterStats' sounds good enough! Thanks. If something else comes to your mind let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

***Attribute*** is the accepted term in RPGs - it predates computer-based RPGs, for sure.

As you rightly say, Attribute is too generic in a software context, and PlayerAttribute is too specific. I think ***CharacterAttribute*** is a good balance - the player is a character, an NPC is a character (a Non-Player Character), and all those values (health, mana, etc) are related to that entity being a character, and not an inanimate object like a crate, or an abstract entity like a zone.

Traditional RPG's make a distinction between NPCs and Monsters, so whether monsters/enemies are characters in the strict sense I don't know. I'd argue that all living things are potentially characters in a game design, though - just that monsters have a very simple personality.

-- Additional info...

The type of value you're talking about is a *Scalar Value* - it has a magnitude (amount), but no direction. To put it another way, it has a single value along only one axis. Scalar values can be plus or minus zero.

With that in mind, your interface could be called 'IScalable' - indicating that it changes a scalar value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually willing to use the very same thing on enemies, the player, etc. Pretty much everything that could have an "Attribute" on it (health, mana, etc) - I'm also not sure if there's a real distinction between Character and monster, but let's assume there is. Since I'm gonna be using the same system on Monsters, is there something even more abstract than the term `Character`? (so that I could use this term, to cover characters and monsters, much like Character, covers Enemy and Player)

Comment: I'd stick with Character, personally - anything more generic is going to be less obvious to anyone reading the code. It's not that monsters and creatures aren't characters - just that old D&D games made a distinction - I don't think you have to stick with that.